# Anaconda installs duplicate libraries

Tags: python, anaconda

I am new to using Anaconda and as my hard drive is filling up I realized there are multiple (large) files that exist as duplicates in the following directories:

```
/anaconda3/pkgs/.../lib/<file>
/anaconda3/lib/<file>
```

Example of a file that is duplicated is `libmklml.dylib`. In addition there are duplicate files such as:

```
tensorflow-base-1.13.1-mkl_py36hc36dc97_0.tar.bz2
tensorflow-base-1.13.1-mkl_py37h66b1bf0_0.tar.bz2
```

in the same directory.

My guess is that the /pkgs/ folders is the file as it was downloaded and the anaconda/lib/ directory is where the libraries are being executed. I am puzzled though why there are duplicate versions of each file.

Can I remove any of them, and if so, how? I tried `conda clean -p` (as well as `conda clean -a`) which seems to have removed about 1.5 Gb of files but not these type of duplicates.

Comment: the easiest solution is to buy a bigger hard drive... ;-)

Comment: Sure, but replacing my SSD on a Macbook Pro is a pricy problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`conda clean -a` is enough for routinely cleanup. Anaconda keep a separated copy for installed package when you do a update. You probably can safely delete all the backups in `/anaconda3/pkgs/`, but it is maybe more wisely leave it to `conda` deal with.

P.S. you can try `miniconda` which have only a few default packages.

Comment: Thanks. If I delete all packages, and later on have to do some update - will those be re-downloaded again or will I end up in a ton of trouble shooting, re-installations etc? I will keep them for now but I want to know if I need that extra space.

Comment: No, `conda` will not re-download those already installed, it will download only the new updates, and it works fine so far (so long as i know). Actually what `conda clean -a` have done is, clean compressed bz files, delete older version package folders, and nothing to the new ones. BUT, i do not known how it will affect other `conda` functions, e.g. `create`. i believe it SHOULD keep `conda`'s way if you do want use `conda `.

Comment: if i conda clean -a or -p from (base), the anaconda3/pkgs folder stays there. I am quite puzzled.. should I remove it manually? The folder contains just .so files.

Answer (score 0):

On linux there is a tool fslint-gui, that finds duplicate files and can then replace the duplicates with a symlink.

Not sure how stable that is when certain packages are updated.