# Anaconda lib duplicates of libonedal_core

Tags: duplicates, anaconda, conda

I'm looking through my Anaconda folders noticing what seem to be many duplicates. All these dupes are modified at the same time, all seem to have a version convention. They are not symlinks.

In `~/opt/anaconda3/lib` and `~/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/dal-2021.5.0-hecd8cb5_782/lib`
[image]
[image]

Are these in fact dupes? If yes, what's the safest way to remove the dupes? I've already run `conda clean -ap` and

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143960/anaconda-installs-duplicate-libraries: `conda clean -a`

Answer (score 1):

These files are very likely symbolic links (softlinks) to a single file. It would be better to examine such files with a `ls -lh` command from a shell, rather than through a GUI. For example, if I look at `libmamba*` in my **base** environment, I see

```bash
$ ls -lh ~/miniconda3/lib/libmamba*
-rwxrwxr-x  2 mfansler  staff   3.2M Aug 23 16:32 libmamba.2.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mfansler  staff    20B Sep 29 17:05 libmamba.2.dylib -> libmamba.2.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mfansler  staff    20B Sep 29 17:05 libmamba.dylib -> libmamba.2.0.0.dylib
```

where the arrows (`->`) represent symbolic links. Also notice how those are only 20 bytes.

Comment: Good point, thanks, I confirmed they are _not_ symlinks and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Peter okay, this looks like a special case, since these are proprietary Intel libraries Anaconda is redistributing. Currently the repackaging script is blindly copying, which I think loses the symlinks. The `dal` package from the **intel** channel is substantially smaller. Please raise an issue on the feedstock: https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/intel_repack-feedstock

Comment: @Peter please file an issue - you found a legitimate bug in the packaging recipe and it’s not something you should manually attempt to clean up (e.g., deleting may trigger package corruption error)